Stata regression table
I need help creating a regression table in Stata for LaTeX. I want to include different regression specifications (in columns) and different outcome variables (in rows) in the same regression table. Here is what I have so far:
Adding Control:
stata
eststo m1: reg y x
eststo m2: reg y x z
esttab m1 m2 using main, se keep(x)

This adds the regression specifications in separate rows.
Different Outcome:
stata
eststo m3: reg c x
eststo m4: reg c x z
esttab m1 m2 using main, se append keep(x)

However, this just appends another table to the first table. I want the second set of regressions to appear in new rows within the same table, instead of being appended as a separate table.
I searched Stata forum for similar problems but did not find anything.
